# Where in tenserflow to show elements

Tags: python, tensorflow

This code shows only indexes of array, where it used

```
tensor1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([1536, 2, 5], dtype='float32'))
tf.where(tensor1 > 3).eval().reshape(1, 2)[0]
```

Output is:

> array([0, 2], dtype=int64)

I did for loop to print using indexes:

```
for i in tf.where(tensor1 > 3).eval().reshape(1, 2)[0]:
    print(tensor1[i].eval())
```

Is there any way to do it without for loop?

Answer (score 0):

tf.gather can also be used to index into arrays, so

```
indices = tf.where(tensor1 > 3)
tf.gather(tensor1, indices)
```

should do the right thing